# how to retrieve data from mongoDb using grails 2.2.2

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

i am developing my first app in grails 2.2.2 and mongoDb.
 But i am stuck in
 **"How to get data from mongoDb and Display In .gsp page"**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [MongoDB plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) in your app, then [Get Start](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html) and [Map Domain Classes to Mongo Collections](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html). Once you are done with mapping, you can use [controllers](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Plug-ins/controllers.html) to [render the mapped Mongo collection](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews) in [Views and Templates](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates).